# Log File for Exchange Authentication

Tags: windows, email, exchange

can somebody tell me the Log file where I can find all the users which were authenticated against my Exchange Server?

Comment: You will have to tell us more about the configuration of the server itself.

Comment: I didn't configure the system by myself. Is there a way that the authentication is handled via EWS?

Comment: Is this on-prem exchange? What version?

Answer (score 0):

You could look for [Mailbox Audit Logging](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/policy-and-compliance/mailbox-audit-logging/mailbox-audit-logging?view=exchserver-2019). Turn it on, and configure it for what you're looking for. Once you do, you'll need to take care to watch out for the growth.